# Why list data turned to str in form validator in Django？

Tags: python, django

I'm using `FBV` in django like below:

```
def handle_recipient(request, pk):
    ...
    if request_method == "PATCH":
        recipient_data = request.json
        print(recipient_data['sale_name'], type(recipient_data['sale_name']))  # [12, 2333] <class 'list'>
        f = BaseMdRecipientForm(recipient_data)
        if f.is_valid():
            ...
```

And my forms defined as:

```
def validate_char(char_value):
    print(char_value, type(char_value)) # [12, 2333] <class 'str'>
    if not isinstance(char_value, str):
        raise ValidationError(
            message="not a valid string value",
            code="invalid"
        )

class BaseMdRecipientForm(forms.Form):
    sale_name = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=128,validators=[validate_char])
    abbreviation = forms.CharField(max_length=64, required=True)
```

My confusion is that the type of `sale_name`  I submitted `{"sale_name":[12,2333],"dsds":"" }` as a format of `application/json` is always different in form validator.

Can you help telling me where `django` make this transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think django is making any transformation. It is just storing everything as a string. Maybe you do not need a validator of type checking like this, instead use a [regex match](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match), like this:

```
import re

def validate_char(char_value):
    if not re.match(r'[A-Za-z0-9 ]+', char_value):
        raise ValidationError(
            message="not a valid string value",
            code="invalid"
        )
```

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me where it `storing everything as a string`?

Comment: Then you need to see how CharField's [to_python](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L1067) method.

Comment: Great! thank you for your patience, and I override `to_python` mrthod for i want to support `"["assd"]"` but not `["assd"]`